# Probability to have exactly 55 heads on 100 coin flips and CLT

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

**What is the probability to have exactly 55 heads out of 100 coin flips ?**

The exact answer is $100\choose{55}$$\frac{1}{2^{100}} \approx 0.0484$

We can see this game as a repetition of Bernoulli($\frac{1}{2}$).

Using CLT : $$P(S_{100}) = 1 - (P(S_{100} \leq 54)+P(S_{100} \geq 56))$$
$$=P(S_{100} \leq 56)-P(S_{100} \leq 54)$$
$$=P(\tilde{S_{100}} \leq \frac{56-50}{5})-P(\tilde{S_{100}} \leq \frac{54-50}{5})$$
$$\approx \Phi(1.2) - \Phi(0.8) \approx 0.097$$

but it's **false**.

So I tried something else : $$P(S_{100}) = P(54.5 \leq S_{100} \leq 55.5)$$
$$\vdots$$
$$\approx \Phi(1.1) - \Phi(0.9) = 0.0484$$
and it **works**.

So I tried again but instead of ($55 \pm\frac{1}{2}$) I tried ($55 \pm 0.8$) and I found $0.0775$.

Why $P(S_{100}) = P(54.5 \leq S_{100} \leq 55.5)$ worked and not the others ? (It should have worked because we are in a discrete case no ?)

Comment: It seems like your post isn’t completed at the end

Comment: I miss clicked the "Post your question" button haha

Comment: What is the phi symbol supposed to mean?

Comment: $\Phi(1.2)-\Phi(0.8)>\Phi(1.1)-\Phi(0.9)$ so $0.1$ for LHS and $0.484$ for RHS must be wrong.

Comment: That's the area under the Gaussian function

Comment: I didn't get it @drhab, 0.484 is the correct answer when I consider $P(S_{100}) = P(54.5 \leq S_{100} \leq 55.5)$

Comment: If indeed $\Phi(1.1)-\Phi(0.9)=0.484$ (I don't exclude that) then automatically $\Phi(1.2)-\Phi(0.8)>0.484$ so cannot equalize $0.097$. Simply because $\Phi(1.2)>\Phi(1.1)$ and $\Phi(0.8)<\Phi(0.9)$.

Comment: I forgot a 0 thanks

Comment: First, you cannot realistically use the CLT in this setting (it gives estimates for $\mathbb{P} (S_n \in [a\sqrt{n}, b\sqrt{n}])$ for large $n$, but fixed $a$ and $b$, and you need very large $n$ if $a$ and $b$ are very close).

Comment: What you need is something else, e.g. a king a *local* CLT. Fortunately, for the binomial, things work out quite well! But indeed, since the integers are $1$ apart, you need to integrate the Gaussian on intervals of length $1$ for this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a "continuity correction". Using a range of $\pm 0.5$ around the discrete points is a good rule.

$\pm 0.8$ is the wrong scale - it's an interval of width $1.6$ rather than $1.$ 
If you divide by $1.6$ you'll get roughly the same answer: $0.0775/1.6\approx 0.0484.$ At the other extreme you can use the density of the pdf, suitable scaled: $1/5\sqrt{2\pi e}\approx 0.0484.$

Comment: http://images.slideplayer.com/24/7326743/slides/slide_10.jpg